# JavaFX Persian DatePicker

Tags: java, javafx

I want to write a Persian Date picker component in `JavaFX`, I looked and checked JDK8's embedded calendar, but you know I need a road map and guideline to start my project. (Oracle documents aren't sufficient, I think)

Comment: I know datePicker but what is Persian ?

Comment: @TilakMadichetti , Hi That's our country calendar ( Farsi - Persian - Jalali Calendar )

Comment: You can set a Chronology on a DatePicker. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/date-picker.htm#sthref250 and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/Chronology.html?is-external=true

Comment: @Jaims I read all of them but there is no implementation of persian calendat to use. I need to write it from scratch.

Comment: See my answer on this [SO-Post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40354105/2491410) with a finished example of a persian datepicker.

Comment: @MenoHochschild I appreciate it.

Comment: please have a look at
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39357121/how-to-implement-persian-calandar