# JavaFX DatePicker, Jalalian calendar

Tags: javafx, datepicker, calendar, persian

I need a Persian calendar DatePicker in JavaFX, but it's not supported yet.
Do you know any alternative solution?

Comment: You can check this [question](http://stackoverflow.duapp.com/questions/39357121/how-to-implement-persian-calandar).

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40354105/2491410) showing my own Jalali calendar picker.